# iPhone Music Organization - Order Numeric, Then Alphabetic

Tags: itunes, iphone, ipod, ipod-touch

More of a preference thing than anything, but is it possible to make the artists have numbers as the starting character show up before the artists with A as the first character? Seems like a lot of other music player programs do that, and I've gotten used to 3 Doors Down being above Abba.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

Apart from changing all the artists to something like "ZZ 3 Doors Down", **it cannot be done**.